vmware NSX 4, Bridge Vlan
I need make Layer 2 connection between PC in vlan 22 that connects to trunk (vmnic5) and an app1 that placed in transport node which connected Zone_overlay.
I tried:

created new segment and segment profile ( Zone_overlay )
set my segment additional setting edge-bridge set Vlan=22
set edge vm vlan portgroup (vlan 4095) note=that is my NVDS-vlan-Uplink

BTW traffic doesn't have any send or receive.
